# Order by in Linq with Web Api 2.0

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api2

I have a controller which retrieves the orders from db, the controllers receives 4 query strings: _page,_perPage,_sortDir and _sortField, my problem is in the sort direction, ASC or DESC dunno why but linq seems to ignore the order I give it to.
First I order by the orderId cause I cannot use the skip method without ordering it, then when I try to order it I cannot do it. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

My controller:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetOrder(int _page, int _perPage,string _sortDir,string _sortField) {

            var order = await db.Order.Select(x => new {
                OrderId = x.OrderId,
                UserId = x.UserId,
                orderStatusCode = x.orderStatusCode
                ---------------
                More Code Not Important
                --------------

                }
            }).OrderBy(x => x.OrderId).Skip((_page - 1) * _perPage).Take(_perPage).ToListAsync();
            switch (_sortDir) {
                case "ASC":
                    order.OrderBy(x=>_sortField);
                    break;
                case "DESC":
                    order.OrderByDescending(x => _sortField);
                    break;
                default:
                    order.OrderBy(x=>x.OrderId);
                    break;
            }
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, order);
            response.Headers.Add("X-Total-Count", db.User.Count().ToString());
            return response;
        }
```

Comment: Looks like you need to use reflection or some other method to turn the string `sortField` into an expression you can use with `OrderBy`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem (on the surface) is that you're not assigning the re-ordered list anywhere.  `OrderBy()` doesn't change the list itself, it returns a new `IEnumerable` that is ordered.  Quickest fix, in your `switch-case`, change each `order.OrderBy(...);` to `order = order.OrderBy(...);`

There may be deeper issues with this question and with this code.  The most obvious being: usually, with a request for alternate ordering in a paged scenario, there is an expectation that the paging is related to the ordering.  However, you have the paging filter with a default ordering, then you order the results.  Note *I'm not aware of your actual requirements*, but in most cases this will generate serious confusion and user error.